# How can we export in one schema and import in another schema without changing anything in exported file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL developer. My schema name is xxx. If I try to export table from my xxx schema, "xxx" the schema name is prefixed with "." separation with the table name. If I need to import it in the different schema database named yyy, I need to change the schema name manually to yyy before impoting.

Is there anyway to do it automatically?

I need a exported code which will work in all databases without any manual intervention. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check off the `Show schema` check box, so the sctipt will be without specific schema name. But you should run it using your `yyy` account.

[image]